# Is there a way to use a mongodb filter directly on on a python list of dicts?

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary

I have a list of dicts inside a variable (let's call it **lod**), and a dict representing a mongodb filter (let's call it **my_filter**). Is there a some way to apply the filter on **lod** without inserting **lod** in a collection ?

To be a bit more clear, I'd like to know if there exists some **magic_function** that would do the following :

```
>>> lod = [{"name": "alice"}, {"name": "bob"}, {"name": "carol"}]
>>> my_filter = {"name": {"$in": ["alice", "carol"]}}
>>> magic_function(lod, my_filter)
[{'name': 'alice'}, {'name': 'carol'}]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perhaps use a mongodb mocking library and implement the magic_function by yourself. 
https://github.com/mongomock/mongomock

Here is an example:

```
def magic_function(lod,my_filter):
    collection = mongomock.MongoClient().db.collection
    for doc in lod:
        collection.insert(doc)

    res = collection.find(my_filter)
    result = []
    for doc in res:
        del doc['_id']
        result.append(doc)
    return result

lod = [{"name": "alice"}, {"name": "bob"}, {"name": "carol"}]

my_filter = {"name": {"$in": ["alice", "carol"]}}

print(magic_function(lod, my_filter))
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for.